# about the boolean parameter copy in np.array function

Tags: python, numpy

i don't understand the significance of the parameter copy=True in the np.array function.I looked up the documentation but couldn't understand it.can you please explain it in simple words for me

Comment: Don't worry about it too much.  Most users don't use it.  The default is ok most of the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.array.html

> **copy : *bool*, *optional***
>
> If true (default), then the object is copied. Otherwise, a copy will
>   only be made if `__array__` returns a copy, if `obj` is a nested sequence,
>   or if a copy is needed to satisfy any of the other requirements
>   (dtype, order, etc.).

When you pass another numpy array to `np.array` you can either copy the contents it to a new object in the memory, or not do that. Normally, you want to copy because you don't want to modify the original array, but there are circumstances where that's not a good thing. When you write

```
a1 = np.array([1, 2, 3])
a2 = np.array(a1, copy=False)
a1[0] = 50
print(a1)
# [50, 2, 3]
print(a2)
# [50  2  3]
```

The original data is not copied. When the original object is very large, it may be a good idea to not copy it to be more memory efficient.

There are three scenarios under which the docs explain a copy will be made anyway even if you set it to false.

1. if `__array__` returns a copy. When you convert an `obj` to a numpy array by `np.array(obj)`, if `obj.__array__` returns a copy of its array content, then numpy object will also contain a copy.
2. Or if a copy is needed to satisfy any of the other requirements.

Here's an example of that.

```
orig = np.array([1, 2, 3])
modified = np.array(orig, dtype=float, copy=False)
modified[0] = 50
print(modified)
# [50.  2.  3.]
print(orig)
# [1, 2, 3]
```

In above example, you are asking numpy to convert all the data to `float`. It cannot possibly do that without copying the data to a new object. So "a copy is needed to satisfy this requirement". numpy will ignore `copy=False`.